# Loading status not showing with nextJs 13 and app structure

Tags: next.js13

What I have:

/app/loading.tsx

```
 const Loading = () => {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  };
  export default Loading;
```

/app/page.tsx

```
  const page: number = +searchParams.page! || 0;
  const limit: number = +searchParams.limit! || 10;

  const response = await fetch(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=${limit}&offset=${page}`
  );
  const data: Data = await response.json();

  return (
    <main className='flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24'>
      {data.results.map((pokemon: Pokemon) => {
        return (
          <div
            key={pokemon.name}
            className='flex flex-col items-center justify-center'
          >
            <p>{pokemon.name}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}

      <TablePaginationDemo data={data} />
    </main>
  );
```

full code: https://github.com/bopavlic/pokemon_v2
live: https://pokemon-v2-git-main-bopavlic.vercel.app/?page=0&limit=10

I tried Wrapping it into `<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}> key={page}` also didn't work.
What is happening right now:
when user clicks on pagination, it takes some time to display new fetched pokemons.
What I want:

After user clicks on pagination, show loading state until new fetched pokemons